# Get fifth level child value from json object with minimal script in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I wanted to get fifth level child value from json object with easiest way without using any third party library.

this is the json object.

```
var datas = {
    "one": [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "two": [
                {"name": "name2"},
                {"name": "name3"},
                {
                    "name": "name4",
                    "three": [
                        {"name": "name5"},
                        {"name": "name6"},
                        {
                          "name": "name6",
                          "four": [
                        {"name": "name5"},
                        {"name": "name6"},
                        {
                          "name": "name6",
                          "five": [
                            {"name": "name5"},
                            {"name": "name6"},
                            {"name": "name6"}
                            ]
                        }
                        ] 
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {"name": "name7"}
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: `datas.one[0].two[2].three[2].four[2].five`. Just follow the structure. Use `["one"]` or `.one` for object properties, and `[0]` or whatever numeric index for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way?

```
datas.one[0].two[2].three[2].four[2].five
```

alternatively

```
datas['one'][0]['two'][2]['three'][2]['four'][2]['five']
```

Comment: Those array indices should be `0` first, and `2` for the rest. JS arrays indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Quite the brain fart - probably due to the named props (I know this *quite* well). Thanks!

Comment: I figured you knew, but thought I'd comment so OP/others wouldn't be confused `:)`